# How to get show_error() in CodeIgniter to load a view?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to load a head view and a foot view in all my pages. But `show_error` uses its own complete template. And it stops execution after it loads this template, so the footer wouldn't even load if I wanted to.

Should I override this method or is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, this is how I did it, and it worked perfectly. I extended `CI_Exceptions` as suggested by Yan Berk, but I was able to use `get_instance` AND load my view.

```
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions {
private $CI;
private $dist;

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    $this->dist = $this->CI->config->item('dist');
}

function show_error($heading, $message, $template = 'error_general', $status_code = 500) {
    $head_data = array("title"=>$this->dist['site_title'].": Error");
    $head = $this->CI->load->view('head', $head_data, TRUE);
    $body = $this->CI->load->view('error_body', $message, TRUE);

    echo $head;
    echo $body;  
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom layout to the error messages in the `application/errors` directory.

EDIT:

If you want to use your existing files you can do one of the following:

1. If you only require the 404 error page, you can set a custom route
   in `config/route.php` under `$route['404_override']`.
2. If you need to handle all error messages, extend the `CI_Exceptions` class with `MY_Exceptions` and using plain PHP, redirect the user to the appropriate page. The exceptions class is loaded before the controller so you cannot use `get_instance()`.

Comment: I know, but that's not what I want. I don't wanna repeat everything I already have in the head view, with all the CSS, javascript used througout the website.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as you said that the class is loaded before the Controller I would not be able to load a view, right? So I'm back to square on. I thought about maybe using a Hook, but I would have the same problem, correct?

Comment: If you use a redirect, everything will be loaded once the redirect is complete since its a totally new request. This will allow you to call the view and perform all tasks required.

Comment: By "use a redirect" you mean modifying CI's core `show_error()` method, right? So instead of displaying a template, it would call my Controller.

Comment: Will try that. I would rather go for a less intrusive way, but I hacked CI's core before, so what the hell? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to hack the core. you can extend `CI_Exceptions`.