# Passing data to view for a custom error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter 2, and I've got a custom 404 working where data is passed to the view using this function in `MY_Exceptions`, because my site's menu is generated dynamically in `site_helper::site_menu()`:

```
 public function show_404($page = '', $log_error = TRUE) {

   $CI =& get_instance();
   $CI->load->helper('site');       
   $this->h['meta'] = site_menu();
   $CI->load->view('templates/header', $this->h);
   $CI->load->view('errors/html/my_error');
   $CI->load->view('templates/footer');
   echo $CI->output->get_output();
   exit;
}
```

This works absolutely brilliantly!

I thought I could use the same idea to override `show_error()`, and as a first iteration, I've tried the following (using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20248981/889604) as inspiration):

```
function show_error($heading, $message, $template = 'error_general', $status_code = 500) {
  $CI =& get_instance();
  $CI->load->view('templates/footer');
  echo $CI->output->get_output();
  exit;
}
```

...but this generates an error:

`Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in /path/to/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 366`

Everything I've tried from every relevant SO question I've found doesn't resolve this... any hints (including advice on moving the dynamic menu if this is likely to help) would be most welcomed!

Comment: My best guess it that for that particular function the Controller hasn't been initialized yet, but it is curious that `show_404` is working :/ Also, not that it would help, but instead of "hacking" the core why don't you just create a `MY_Exceptions` or are you overriding the functions in common?

Comment: @Alex - yeh, that's why I'm confused too! Yes, that code snippet is in a MY_Exceptions class :)

Comment: Not that it would help, but have you tried initializing the instance in the class constructor rather than individually per function as the answerer Christian Dechery suggests? I don't have CI 2, so just troubleshooting here

Comment: @Alex, yea, I've tried that too... :/